# How can I achieve the view like below image? I want to make the view from xml using Roatation

Tags: android, rotation

[image]

Please help I already do like the view like screenshot 2 but having a problem to achieve like screenshot 1.Is it possible to do?

View with rotation with feel the screen.[image]

Thanks in advance.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:rotation="165"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/header"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should say that what you're trying to accomplish would be best achieved with a background drawable with the shape you want, rather than trying to rotate views to look like this. It's simply a lot of work and views to achieve something that a basic knowledge in microsoft paint would achieve as well.

That being said, to get your desired result, you just need to apply the pivot points of the view you're rotating to the top left corner (0, 0), and rotate only 15 degrees in the opposite direction"

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:transformPivotX="0dp"
    android:transformPivotY="0dp"
    android:rotation="-15"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark" />
```

You might also need to make the view a bit longer, since the rotation will mean the view doesn't extend to the edge of the screen (due to pythagorean's theorem). You could do this by applying a large dp value for the view's width, or by setting the view's scaleX property to 1.5, or something similar.

Comment: Ok. Your suggestion is good.Can you please give any reference or code for that.So I can understand.Actually I know about shape drawable but no idea about how to use it for these kind of Custom view.If you help me than it really appreciable.

Comment: I want to put FloatingActionButton on this view's edge like material design do.Is it possible?
And Thank you verry much for your ans It work like a charm

Comment: The pivot point is the point around which you rotate - you can think of it as the point you hold the view with your finger while you're rotating the view. The default pivot point is the center of the view. What I suggested about creating the background - I meant, just draw the background you want, save it as a png, and use that as the background of your view. You can also do this with a shape xml file, but if you don't know how to do this, I suggest you read a bit about it before asking another question.

Comment: Positioning the FAB perfectly on the line is possible with a bit of trigonometry - but only via the code. If we know the FAB's centerX position, and we know the rotation degree is -15, to find the FAB's centerY position, the formula is: centerY = (centerX * Math.sin(-15)) / Math.sin(105). If you want the FAB to be below the line, simply add half the FAB's height to centerY (+ any additional padding).

Comment: If I set margins like  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
like this than It will worked but I am confused for all resolution support.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Gil

Comment: This solution is good but in Samsung Tab2 Line of the view is separated into pixels.So your second solution may help but it also gives same result.Please help